# Shift cell upwards in R programming

Tags: r, google-analytics, analytics, data-science, data-analysis

[image]![enter image description here][2]
How can I shift values upwards in R programming? I have attached the image as an example. ATTACHED IMAGE MIGHT GIVE MORE CLARITY ABOUT MY QUESTION. It seems very challenging and tough to me. And I want to fix the empty cells as NA. I wish I could solve this, but unfortunately could not. Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: Please try to explain with your words instead than inserting external link to an image. Reformulating your problem might help you solve it

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your needs, you may do the following steps:

```
library(stringi)

# prepare the initial dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(
        rbind(
        c('aaaa','1000','','','','3000','4000'),
        c('bbbb','','2000','3000','','','5000'),
        c('cccc','','','','5000','','5000'),
        c('dddd','','','2000','3000','','5000'),
        c('eeee','','','','4000','4000','8000')
    ))

# define its column names
colnames(df) <- c("ID","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","Total")

# here's the dataframe
df

    ID 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 Total
1 aaaa 1000                3000  4000
2 bbbb      2000 3000            5000
3 cccc                5000       5000
4 dddd           2000 3000       5000
5 eeee                4000 4000  8000

# create a working function
compact_rows <- function(vect) {

    str <- stri_remove_empty(head(vect, length(vect)-1), na_empty = FALSE)        

    return(c(as.character(str), as.character(rep(NA, length(vect)-length(str) - 1)), tail(vect,1)))

}

# build the final dataframe
new_df <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, compact_rows)))

# define its column names
colnames(new_df) <- c("ID","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","Total")

# here's the final dataframe
new_df

    ID 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 Total
1 aaaa 1000 3000 <NA> <NA> <NA>  4000
2 bbbb 2000 3000 <NA> <NA> <NA>  5000
3 cccc 5000 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  5000
4 dddd 2000 3000 <NA> <NA> <NA>  5000
5 eeee 4000 4000 <NA> <NA> <NA>  8000
```

Comment: You're welcome, you may close the question as answered. That would be useful for anyone else with the same prb.